# nestjs jest times out after 10 minutes circleci

Tags: testing, jestjs, continuous-integration, nestjs, circleci

I have a nestjs application that has a jest e2e test suite. Running it locally takes roughly 13s~. However when trying to run them on circleci, the tests hangs and does not seem to exit successfully. They timeout at 10 minutes and fails. I am not sure what causes this behaviour.

[image]

`/.circleci/config.yml`

```yaml
version: 2.1
jobs:
  run_tests:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:10
    steps:
      - checkout #cloning git repo
      - run:
          name: Install npm dependencies
          command: |
            npm install --save
      - run:
          name: Run unit tests
          command: |
            NODE_ENV=test && node node_modules/.bin/jest
          environment:
            DATABASE_URL: postgres://_:_:@localhost:5432/testdb
      - run:
          name: Run e2e tests
          command: |
            NODE_ENV=test && node --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand --config ./test/jest-e2e.json --watchAll=false
          environment:
            DATABASE_URL: postgres://_:_:@localhost:5432/testdb
      - store_test_results:
          path: test-results
workflows:
  build_test:
    jobs:
      - run_tests
```

`test/jest-e2e.json`

```json
{
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "ts"],
  "rootDir": ".",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testRegex": ".e2e-spec.ts$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "verbose": true
}
```

test setup

```
beforeAll(async () => {
    const rootModule: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [RootModule]
    }).compile();

    app = rootModule.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
    shopboxService = app.select(ShopboxModule).get(ShopboxService);
    clothesService = app.select(ClothesModule).get(ClothesService);
    await shopboxService.deleteTags();
  });

  it('authenticates a user and includes a jwt token in the response', async () => {
    const response = await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post('/auth/login')
      .send({ email: 'myemail@example.com', password: '123456789' })
      .expect(201);

    adminAccessToken = response.body.token;

    expect(adminAccessToken).toMatch(
      /^[A-Za-z0-9-_=]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_=]+\.?[A-Za-z0-9-_.+/=]*$/
    );
  });
```

test teardown

```
  afterAll(async () => {
    try {
      await shopboxService.deleteTags();
    } catch (e) {
      console.warn('error', e);
    } finally {
      await app.close();
    }
  });
```

After deleting --inspect-brk circleci started providing feedback from the tests.

```
FAIL  test/user-store-reservation-flow.e2e-spec.ts (37.493 s)
  User create store reservation flow
    ✕ authenticates a user and includes a jwt token in the response (2 ms)
    ✕ authenticates a user and includes a jwt token in the response
    ✕ creates a user
    ✕ creates a reservation, check that it exists in shopbox (4 ms)
    ✕ create clothing on storeReservation, check that it has the right properties
    ✕ check that clothing exists in shopbox, and has correct price, barcode, user, tag and reservation (1 ms)
    ✕ fails when persisting another one, should not persist to shopbox
    ✕ updating shopbox stock should retrieve stock 1
    ✕ get current reservations should return 1 (1 ms)
    ✕ should not be able to create a second reservation
    ✕ delete clothing should fail on user, but be accepted as employee
    ✕ delete clothing should fail on user, but be accepted as employee
    ✕ create a new piece of clothing and assert that it exists in the db and shopbox (1 ms)
    ✕ delete reservation and check that the clothing and reservation is terminated in postgres and does not exist in shopbox

  ● User create store reservation flow › authenticates a user and includes a jwt token in the response

    Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 30000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 30000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

      at mapper (../node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:27:45)

  ● User create store reservation flow › authenticates a user and includes a jwt token in the response

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'getHttpServer' of undefined

      38 | 
      39 |   it('authenticates a user and includes a jwt token in the response', async () => {
    > 40 |     const response = await request(app.getHttpServer())
         |                                        ^
      41 |       .post('/auth/login')
      42 |       .send({ email: '_', password: '123456789' })
      43 |       .expect(201);

      at Object.it (user-store-reservation-flow.e2e-spec.ts:40:40)
```

I am not sure why this fails, since it works as expected locally.

Also after running the tests it seems like a database connection is not shut down properly

```
Time:        37.537 s
Ran all test suites.
[Nest] 624   - 11/21/2020, 12:37:07 AM   [ExceptionHandler] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
[Nest] 624   - 11/21/2020, 12:37:40 AM   [ExceptionHandler] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (2)... +33005ms
[Nest] 624   - 11/21/2020, 12:38:13 AM   [ExceptionHandler] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (3)... +33007ms
[Nest] 624   - 11/21/2020, 12:38:46 AM   [ExceptionHandler] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (4)... +33004ms
[Nest] 624   - 11/21/2020, 12:39:19 AM   [ExceptionHandler] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (5)... +33005ms
[Nest] 624   - 11/21/2020, 12:39:52 AM   [ExceptionHandler] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (6)... +33006ms
```

Comment: Hey Jonas, do you need this `--inspect-brk` in your CI command? Also the timeout seems to be a default setup on CircleCI not jest.

Comment: @IvanSantos I don't think I do, I think I added it for debugging some time ago. I have removed it and running the pipeline again

Comment: @IvanSantos it actually made a pretty huge difference, now circleci provides test information!

Comment: looks like your tests are not able to connect to the database. Check the configs for that.

Comment: @IvanSantos yeah, I suspect it is mongo since the application is using that for logs. I have to fiddle with the ``config.yml`` I assume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were multiple errors. In the beginning it was hanging because `--inspect-brk`, because it sets a breakpoint for debugging in the start of the program.

Then I encountered multiple errors with my two databases postgres and mongodb. They either hung or could not connect properly.

To make it work I had to

- Set up a Mongodb image in the container
- Set up a Postgres image in the container
- Install extensions for postgres
- Remove the encapsulating transaction in the seeding script.

`.circleci/config.yml`

```yaml
version: 2.1
jobs:
  run_tests:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:10
      - image: circleci/postgres:9.6.8-alpine-postgis
        auth:
          username: ?
          password: ? # context / project UI env-var reference
        environment:
          POSTGRES_USER: ?
          POSTGRES_DB: ?
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ?
      - image: circleci/mongo:4.4.1
        environment:
          DATABASE_URL: mongodb://localhost/?
    steps:
      - checkout #alias for git clone\
      - run:
          name: Installing psql client
          command: |
            sudo apt install postgresql-client
      - run:
          name: Waiting for PostgreSQL to start
          command: |
            for i in `seq 1 10`;
            do
              nc -z localhost 5432 && echo Success && exit 0
              echo -n .
              sleep 2
            done
            echo Failed waiting for Postgres && exit 1
      - run:
          name: Installing postgres contributions
          command: |
            sudo apt-get -qq update
            sudo apt-get -qq install postgresql-contrib
      - run:
          name: Restarting postgres
          command: |
            sudo service postgresql restart
      - run:
          name: Install extensions for postgres
          command: |
            psql -U ? -d ? -h localhost -p 5432 -c "CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;"
      - run:
          name: Waiting for MongoDB to be ready
          command: |
            for i in `seq 1 30`;
            do
              nc -z localhost 27017 && echo Success && exit 0
              echo -n .
              sleep 1
            done
            echo Failed waiting for MongoDB && exit 1
      - run:
          name: Install npm dependencies
          command: |
            npm install --save
      - run:
          name: Run unit tests
          command: |
            NODE_ENV=test && node node_modules/.bin/jest
      - run:
          name: Run e2e tests
          command: |
            NODE_ENV=test && node node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand --config ./test/jest-e2e.json --watchAll=false --detectOpenHandles
      - store_test_results:
          path: test-results
      - store_artifacts:
          path: test-results

workflows:
  build_test:
    jobs:
      - run_tests
```

It is probably inefficient, having to install the psql client and dependencies in this way.